# Cannot set ports to listening even though they have been opened Windows/Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, firewall, port, windows-firewall

Currently trying to set up a connection (using sockets) between my localPC (windows) and my VM (Ubuntu). They are both on the same subnet and can be pinged.

Went into Windows features, advanced settings, added an inbound rule and outbound rule for the port number (set local and remote port to the same number). There is a green tick beside both the inbound and outbound rules.
The command `netstat-an` does not show my port. So i cant tell if its even open.

Inside Ubuntu, I ran the command: `sudo ufw allow ###/tcp`. 
However, when I run:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

However I still cannot seem to figure out if the port is open or not.
Note: The port used does not conflict with any other application's port.

**Troubleshooting:**

I can still ping both the systems from each other.
When I run netcat on my local PC (Windows) as such:

```
ncat ip_of_vm ###
Ncat: No connection could be made because the remote machine refused it
```

When I run Netcat on the VM (Ubuntu) towards my local-PC:

```
nc ip_of_localPC ###
```

It just hangs. No error message.

**Background**

I am trying to run a simple client and server side java program. I just cant seem to figure out how to get the ports to work

Comment: Do you have a service listening on the port that you opened?

Comment: isn't nc supposed to act as a service to check if the ports are open?

Comment: It will only show a response if you have something is listening on that port.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your ufw says inactive is that before you can open ports with it you need to run `sudo ufw enable`. However that's not my suggested solution because at the current time with ufw disabled there is no firewall to close the ports in the first place.

On your server machine run `nc -l ###` on the client run the command as you were before. The `-l` option makes netcat listen for an incoming connection.